# JSON String containing HTLM, convert to JSON in Python

Tags: python, html, json, escaping

I have a JSON string (see below code example), which contains HTML in one of the values.
WHen I run this I get:

> 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column
> 32 (char 57)'

Which is presumably because of the escaping?
The HTML lines probably contain invalid HTML, but I would like to know the best way to deal with this within a Python JSON context.
Here is my exmaple code:

```
import json

jsonString = """{
      "Key1": "Value1",
      "Key2": "<p><span style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10pt;\">&nbsp;king@kong.com&nbsp;\r\n</span></p>",
      "Key3": "Value3"
      }"""

response = json.loads(jsonString)
print(jsonString)
```

Thanks.